# How to add bottom view to a Coordinator Layout with view pager?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-coordinatorlayout

I want to add a bottom view to a `Coordinator` layout with `view pager` in it , Bottom View will be on top of `fragment` loaded by `view pager` and independent of it .

I added a `linear layout` with

```
layout_gravity = "bottom"
```

but bottom view `linear layout` is not showing at all

Following is my `xml` layout of the `activity`.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/maintoolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/maintabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>





<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/mainviewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/completeBottomView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBarBottomView"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:max="100"
        android:progress="1"/>

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/limiter_scroller"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|start"
        android:background="#FF3399"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/limiter_layout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:onClick="clickFromBottomView"/>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

</LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: add completeBottomView inside framelayout try

Answer (score 54, accepted):

As pointed out in comment by @Dhawal ....Solution is to wrap `LinearLayout` completeBottomView in a `FrameLayout` with `android:layout_gravity="bottom"`

Comment: this fixed my problem. had an edittext anchored to the bottom that i needed appear about the keyboard when it gained focus. cheers

Comment: Adding `android:layout_gravity="bottom"` directly to your LinearLayout (completeBottomView) should work as well. I don't think the additional FrameLayout is necessary

Comment: Doesn't this mean that the content of the bottom view will overlap the other content?

Comment: Any solution? The bottom view is covering part of the content of my viewPager

Comment: Not a solution specially if you need translucent bar with `fitsSystemWindows`

Answer (score 7):

**Android CoordinatorLayout Bottom Layout Behaviour.**

***activity_bottom.xml***

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#C0C0C0"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"            
        app:layout_behavior="com.utils.behaviour.BottomLayoutBehavior">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#007432"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Footer View"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="25sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

***BottomLayoutBehavior.kt***

```
package com.utils.behaviour

import android.content.Context
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.view.View
import androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat
import kotlin.math.max
import kotlin.math.min

class BottomLayoutBehavior<V : View>(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?) :
    CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<V>(context, attrs) {

    override fun onStartNestedScroll(
        coordinatorLayout: CoordinatorLayout, child: V,
        directTargetChild: View, target: View, axes: Int, type: Int
    ): Boolean {
        return axes == ViewCompat.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL
    }

    override fun onNestedPreScroll(
        coordinatorLayout: CoordinatorLayout, child: V,
        target: View, dx: Int, dy: Int, consumed: IntArray, type: Int
    ) {
        child.translationY = max(
            0f,
            min(child.height.toFloat(), child.translationY + dy)
        )
        super.onNestedPreScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, target, dx, dy, consumed, type)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me.
Change `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"` to `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"` attribute of android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.
More details [here](http://www.journaldev.com/12858/android-tablayout-appbarlayout)